# How to change unit of data in dygraph

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am using dygraph for my project which displays time to first byte and loadtime of a page in milliseconds, but i want it to be displayed in seconds. How can i achieve this? [image: Here is the screenshot of my graph]

For example here it is displayed that ttfb and loadtime is 6372 and 8655, 14953 and 13858 All i want is it should be 6.372 and 8.655, 14.953 and 13.858. the data which i am giving as input are in csv format.

here is the jade file in which i am writing code to display graph using dygraph.

[image]

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: I have provided the code above.

Comment: Please copy paste the code snippet and format it instead of pasting the screenshot. That would save time of others who is reading your question!

Comment: Checkout the [axisLabelFormatter](http://dygraphs.com/per-axis.html) option

Comment: You want to set a [`valueFormatter`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#valueFormatter) on the x-axis. Or just make your data be time in seconds, if that's what you want to display.

Comment: i tried converting data to seconds before saving it into the database but the problem is dygraph is reading it as milliseconds, say i got 16834 as loadtime and i saved it as 16.834 but then dygraph is reading it as 16.834 milliseconds not as seconds.

Comment: Its working now @danvk

Comment: @danvk according to your solution the data is getting converted into the desired format, but the problem is the data which you can see with the data in the above screen shot is also getting changed to epoch after using value formatter function. what to do